# Declaring script dependencies between scripts enqueued with different action hooks

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

Consider this scenario:

I enqueued some scripts in my custom theme. Then I set off to building a plugin that I want to be used only with that one theme. I want to enqueue other scripts in my plugin that depend on scripts enqueued in the theme. The standard way of declaring script dependencies in wordpress is passing an array of dependencies to `wp_enqueue_script`. E.g.:

`wp_enqueue_script('tagsinput-scripts', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js', array('bootstrap-js'), '130215', false);`

would not be enqueued until `bootstrap-js` is enqueued.

Imagine that the script above was enqueued by my plugin with `admin_enqueue_scripts` action hook, while `bootstrap-js` was enqueued in the theme with the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook.

Can the dependency between `tagsinput-scripts` and `bootstrap-js` be properly resolved by Wordpress in this scenario when the two scripts where enqueued using different action hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is, "No". Although `admin_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_enqueue_scripts` hooks does exactly the same thing, the do their work in separate places which do not have any reference to the other.

- `wp_enqueue_scripts` runs on the public side or front end
- `admin_enqueue_scripts` As the name suggests, it runs on the admin side or back end

Your script that with the dependency will thus never load if it is depended on a script that is loaded via the other hook.

You will have to hook your `bootstrap-js` to both hooks for this to work, this will ensure that your dependency will work as well

Example:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_bootstrap_js' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_bootstrap_js' );

function enqueue_bootstrap_js()
{
    //Register and enqueue your bootstrap-js script
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tagsinput_scripts' );

function tagsinput_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('tagsinput-scripts', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js', array('bootstrap-js'), '130215', false);
}
```

Comment: Thnak you for this detailed reply. It helped me a lot.

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is "Yes".

Using `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `admin_enqueue_scripts` does make the script a dependency however it will only be recallable in the local environment. Thus only in the theme or plugin where you are registering it. However what what Pieter Goosen nor WordPress doesn't tell you is that you can use the `wp_default_scripts` hook to register an installation wide script.

**How to use?** See the note below, what's currently awaiting moderation for the "User Contributed Notes" of the [`wp_default_scripts` action hook at the WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_default_scripts).

---

Add a script where you can refer to from anywhere in your WordPress installation using `wp_enqueue_script` or `admin_enqueue_script`.

First setup the hook, for example in your plugin.

```
add_action('wp_default_scripts', function(&$scripts) {
  // Arguments order: `$scripts->add( 'handle', 'url', 'dependencies', 'version', 'in_footer' );`
  // Set "in_footer" argument to 1 to output the script in the footer.
  $scripts->add('my-plugin-script', '/path/to/my-plugin-script.js', array('jquery'), 'alpha', 1);
});
```

Now you can use the script from the plugin anywhere for example in your theme.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
  // Note the third argument: `array('my-plugin-script')`
  wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-script', '/path/to/my-theme-script.js', array('my-plugin-script'), null, true);
});
```

Please make sure that you pick an identical string for the "handle" argument, a good practice is prefixing the handle name with your plugin or theme name.

Comment: This is possibly the only place on the internet that has this answer! I've been trying to solve this problem for many hours and this seems like a very promising solution.

Comment: I upvoted your comment on WP Dev Resources.  Not sure who downvoted it, but this is a great piece of information.